# Azure table storage backup and restore

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way I can do backup of Azure Table Storage into VM or on Azure BLOB.

And also a way to restore backup files from VM to Azure Table Storage if something goes wrong.

Automated script, program using C#/Python etc will work here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AzCopy v8 to do so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#export-data-from-table-storage